# How do I fix the left margin in a div to work in the middle of a lot of paragraphs

Tags: html, margin, paragraph

Hi and thanks in advance for help.  I'M A BEGINNER-PLEASE HELP ME AS SIMPLY AS POSSIBLE.

I have a column of data.  In the middle is some stuff I want left indented about 15px, this is the paragraph.  It won't indent.  I have paragraphs above and below without div's that indent correctly.  Only this one with the div and box doesn't indent on the left.  What do i do?
THANKS:
1ST PARAGRAPH & 3RD PARAGRAPH ARE PERFECT, MIDDLE PARAGRAPH WON'T INDENT.

```
  <p style="margin-left: 25px"><a href="/Hayley/victory"><font size="+2">$83,000 SETTLEMENT</a><br> Our client was injured when she fell in a theatre that had installed a dangerous temporary lighting board system...</p> 

 <p><font color="#556B2F"><div style="width:600px;height:100px;border:4px solid #349554; background:Chartreuse"; "margin-left:15px;">YOU WILL GET ABOUT 3 &frac12 TIMES MORE MONEY BY HIRING AN ATTORNEY COMPARED TO SETTLING A CASE ON YOUR OWN.*</div></font></p>

  <p style="margin-left: 25px"><a href="/Hayley/victory"><font size="+2">$25,000 SETTLEMENT</a><br> Our client was burned on the leg at a spa when she was receiving a treatment...</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just didn't define the margin left property in the style tag.  this should be it.

```
 <p>
    <font color="#556B2F">
      <div style="width:600px;height:100px;border:4px solid #349554; background:Chartreuse; margin-left:15px;" >YOU
        WILL GET ABOUT 3 &frac12 TIMES MORE MONEY BY HIRING AN ATTORNEY COMPARED TO SETTLING A CASE ON YOUR OWN.*</div>
    </font>
  </p>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly.  Sorry but I'm new.  Why exactly did it work -if you have the time.  Thanks again.

Comment: why it doesn't work is not a very difficult question. If you want to style by typing inline css in Html, you have to do it in the style = "" tags. You wrote it this way : `<div style="width:600px;height:100px;border:4px solid #349554; background:Chartreuse"`; **"margin-left:15px;"**. If you notice here, the margin-left property is written outside the end tag.    but it had to be in the quotation(" your all styles must be here ") marks. Because when style opens, you must define it in the same quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks what a pain in the butt fussy language-oh well.  I see I have to be extra careful with all the little details.  First website done-thanks to your final edit & all resolved.  If you ever need legal help, give us a call.  Now, I have to figure out how to mark this resolved.